# Google Sheets How to Filter Column Based on Cell Reference

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, gs-vlookup

**Background**
I have a sheet I use for managing software installed in computer labs at our college. Column A contains a list of software titles. Row 1 contains all the lab names, and all the cells in between contain a status of whether or not the software is installed.

[image: Master Sheet]

I then have tabs for each building where end users can reference particular labs to see what software is available in each lab. My sheet in these tabs currently uses a simple filter function where I am manually referencing each column that corresponds with the lab name.

`=filter(Master!$A$19:$A$202,Master!F$19:F$202<>"")`

**Question**
Instead of manually setting the column for each filter, I want to filter based on the column that matches the lab name on my master sheet in row 1.

[image: Reference Sheets]

Something like: Filter(Master!$A$19:$A$202, match column from lab name & where the same column <>"")

I apologize if what I am trying to accomplish isn't clear. I basically need to combine an HLOOKUP with FILTER I am thinking. Thank you in advance!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here is a copy: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T2zB_-Oi_AOC3BknMwomKlYo7gdd32S-0z-7Bw_-Fgs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER({Master!A$19:B$202, INDIRECT("Master!"&
 ADDRESS(19,  MATCH(A1, Master!$1:$1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(202, MATCH(A1, Master!$1:$1, 0))), Master!B$19:B$202}, 
 INDIRECT("Master!"&
 ADDRESS(19,  MATCH(A1, Master!$1:$1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(202, MATCH(A1, Master!$1:$1, 0)))<>"")
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D01D38woWOsisEG8daYuJIICsJoQWX3X1okRLWTpMtM/edit#gid=123656191)